# Web Parts Maintenance Page error

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, error

I have now in a longere periode of time had this below error occuring, when interacting with one of the WebParts in the SP environment. I have searched the google, this site and other sites, but I cannot finde any good reason to how to solve it.

For some users it works fine, for others it crash, with the

> An unexpected error has occurred.
>
> Web Parts Maintenance Page: If you have permission, you can use this
>   page to temporarily close Web Parts or remove personal settings. For
>   more information, contact your site administrator. "

And the log description for the error is below.

> System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.  Parameter name:
>   uriString    at System.Uri..ctor(String uriString)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite..ctor(String requestUrl)     at
>   MyWebPart.Core.ListConfiguration.<>c__DisplayClass1.b__0()
>   at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity.<>c__DisplayClass4.b__2()
>   at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SecurityContext.RunAsProcess(CodeToRunElevated
>   secureCode)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(WaitCallback
>   secureCode, Object param)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(CodeToRunElevated
>   secureCode)     at
>   MyWebPart.Core.ListConfiguration.GetKeyValue(String key)     at
>   MyWebPart.VisualWebPart1.VisualWebPart1UserControl.FillFilterBoxes(...    6dd24153-ec4e-4610-b8de-61b4e2fae993
>
> 08/08/2014 11:10:55.41*   w3wp.exe (0x014C)
>     0x0560  SharePoint Foundation           Runtime
>     tkau    Unexpected  ...)     at
>   MyWebPart.VisualWebPart1.VisualWebPart1UserControl.Page_Load(Object
>   sender, EventArgs e)     at
>   System.Web.Util.CalliHelper.EventArgFunctionCaller(IntPtr fp, Object
>   o, Object t, EventArgs e)     at
>   System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender,
>   EventArgs e)     at System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e)     at
>   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()     at
>   System.Web.UI.Control.AddedControl(Control control, Int32 index)
>   at MyWebPart.VisualWebPart1.VisualWebPart1.CreateChildControls() 
>   at System.Web.UI.Control.EnsureChildControls()     at
>   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()     at
>   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()     at
>   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()     at
>   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderR...   6dd24153-ec4e-4610-b8de-61b4e2fae993
>
> 08/08/2014 11:10:55.41*    w3wp.exe (0x014C)
>     0x0560  SharePoint Foundation           Runtime
>     tkau    Unexpected  ...ecursiveInternal()     at
>   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()     at
>   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()     at
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean
>   includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) 6dd24153-ec4e-4610-b8de-61b4e2fae993

I have tried to troubleshoot it, but I cannot come any closer to the solution. It has worked fine for some years, but suddenly it begins to crash. And again it is yet not for all users only some.

So far it works in-house, but crash for some on the VPN/APN, but I do not think that this could be a reason, for it has worked fine until this week.

Any ideas?

----- Addition new error fixed by kicking the WFE out of the LoadBalancer-----

> Unexpected    System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. 
>   Parameter name: uriString    at System.Uri..ctor(String uriString)
>   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite..ctor(String requestUrl)     at
>   MyWebPart.Core.ListConfiguration.<>c__DisplayClass1.b__0()
>   at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity.<>c__DisplayClass4.b__2()
>   at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SecurityContext.RunAsProcess(CodeToRunElevated
>   secureCode)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(WaitCallback
>   secureCode, Object param)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(CodeToRunElevated
>   secureCode)     at MyWebPart.Core.ListConfiguration.GetKeyValue(String
>   key)     at
>   MyWebPart.VisualWebPart1.VisualWebPart1UserControl.FillFilterBoxes(...    9e7d36a2-67e7-4b4d-ad7f-93e92a897501
>
> 08/11/2014 09:09:53.83*   w3wp.exe (0x0FE8)
>     0x0F98  SharePoint Foundation           Runtime
>     tkau    Unexpected  ...)     at
>   MyWebPart.VisualWebPart1.VisualWebPart1UserControl.Page_Load(Object
>   sender, EventArgs e)     at
>   System.Web.Util.CalliHelper.EventArgFunctionCaller(IntPtr fp, Object
>   o, Object t, EventArgs e)     at
>   System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender,
>   EventArgs e)     at System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e)     at
>   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()     at
>   System.Web.UI.Control.AddedControl(Control control, Int32 index)
>   at MyWebPart.VisualWebPart1.VisualWebPart1.CreateChildControls()
>   at System.Web.UI.Control.EnsureChildControls()     at
>   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()     at
>   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()     at
>   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()     at
>   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderR...   9e7d36a2-67e7-4b4d-ad7f-93e92a897501
>
> 08/11/2014 09:09:53.83*   w3wp.exe (0x0FE8)
>     0x0F98  SharePoint Foundation           Runtime
>     tkau    Unexpected  ...ecursiveInternal()     at
>   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()     at
>   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()     at
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean
>   includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) 9e7d36a2-67e7-4b4d-ad7f-93e92a897501
>
> 08/11/2014 09:09:53.85    w3wp.exe (0x0FE8)
>     0x0F98  SharePoint Foundation           Monitoring
>     b4ly    Medium      Leaving Monitored Scope (Request
>   (GET:http://xxxx.com:80/subiste/subsite/Pages/MyStartPage.aspx)).
>   Execution Time=110,412426719038   9e7d36a2-67e7-4b4d-ad7f-93e92a897501

Answer (score 2):

Looking at your error that it's reporting:

1. Go to the project:

   ```
   MyWebPart
   ```
2. Go to the class:

   ```
   VisualWebPart1UserControl
   ```

within that class you have a control that is called:

```
FillFilterBoxes
```

It is that control that is throwing the null value exception! The error clearly states

> 'Value cannot be null'

so the default value needs not be null.

What control is it?  `FillFilterBoxes` is the name you gave the control.

Comment: Not my code. But it seems to work now, after the network balancing has been restarted. They did not send propper request, according to our network-guy. I really appriciate that you used time to take a look at the error-log. I will though try to finde the code and look at the FillFilterBoxes part.

Comment: lol i did take it out of my edit as i wasnt sure if it was the case, but i metioned that it could be the fact that the vpn was losing packets or took too long so it caused the filter control to have the value of null.... that would explain why it would work sometimes on vpn but not all the time and some users.. it would also explain why it works in-house as its quick compared over vpn

Comment: Thanks, I would never have thought about it that way. So just a follow op, the problem occured the second day, but now for all, not just them on VPN or on wireless but also in-house. Found that one of the WFEs logged the error every time it occured, shut that WFE down, and everything is now working and perfect. So there must be something wrong on that particular WFE.

Comment: is it producing the same error as you posted every time?

Comment: Not all the same. It was still the mainenance page error, but in the logs it showed some runtime error, where the runtime was over 60 seconds. But the business is running on two WFEs now, instead of three, and that is okay, no need for three, but I still would like to finde out what is wrong on the "fault" WFE.

Comment: can you post the error, i might be able to help

Comment: Hi, thanks again. I have added the error to my initial post, under the dotted line. The last line, Excecution time is very long, I think. Again, I do not belive that there is anything with the code, because it has worked and it works great on the other two WFEs.

Comment: As is read it, all the errors are the same, except the last line in the added error, that one with execution time.